# What is the χ2 score representing relative contribution in the Cox proportional hazards model？ How to get?

Tags: survival, chi-squared-test, cox-model, likelihood

I am reading a paper named "[Clinical scoring system to predict hepatocellular carcinoma in chronic hepatitis B carriers](https://doi.org/10.1200/jco.2009.26.2675)"  and confused about how to construct the prediction score by weights of significant variables.
The paper said :"A simple risk score was devised by using significant variables obtained from stepwise multivariate analysis with P < .05. The score was the weighted sum of those variables of which the weights were defined as the quotient (rounded to nearest integer) of corresponding estimated coefficient from a Cox regression analysis divided by the smallest χ2 coefficient."
What is χ2 coefficient of Cox proportional hazards model? And how to get χ2 coefficient of each significant variable.

Thanks!!
Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

The $\chi^2$ values shown in Table 2 of the cited paper seem to be those used for Wald tests on the coefficient estimates. It's the square of the ratio of a coefficient estimate to its standard error. In this case all of the Wald statistics seem to be based on single degrees of freedom, so they are the squares of *z*-statistics that other software like R might report. Those are included in standard summaries of Cox models.

That said, I don't see how the authors get the "weights" they report in Table 3 from the hazard ratios and $\chi^2$ values in Table 2, if you follow their explanation. If anything, the "weights" seem to be related to the *inverse* of what the authors state. For example, the hazard ratios associated with `age` and `bilirubin` are almost the same, the $\chi^2$ value for `age` is twice that for `bilirubin`, and the weight for `age` is also twice that for `bilirubin`. If you divided the Cox coefficients or HR by the $\chi^2$ values you would get "weights" in the opposite order for those predictors.

There also seems to be some additional scaling, not just rounding, involved to get the values reported for "weights."

Note that the $\chi^2$ tests in this report aren't strictly correct, as the authors used stepwise selection to build the multiple-regression model but didn't that that into account in the tests. A $\chi^2$ test assumes that you didn't use the outcomes to design the model, but stepwise selection necessarily does that.

Comment: Thanks for your patient and perceptive explanation, and I benefited a lot from your answer. I think you are right about the χ2  values obtained from Wald tests. So, it is exactly inconsistent about the calculation of the "weights" and the stepwise multivariate analysis seemed to just aim for choosing the significant variables.

Comment: I really don't understand why the authors used χ2 values instead of coefficients from multivariate  Cox regression analysis, like most studies do. I think only the authors konw why! Anyway, my question is solved and I learned how to calculate χ2 value of Wald tests. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!

Comment: @XinXu the chi-square statistic (corrected for the number of degrees of freedom) isn't a bad way to evaluate relative contributions of predictors to a model. See Chapter 5 of [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate.html#sec-val-bootrank). You are correct that there are better ways to make predictions from a model, like [nomograms](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/coxcase.html#presenting-the-model). If this answers your question, please accept the answer so that others can focus their attention on un-answered questions.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me about the meaning of  the chi-square statistic, and my question have been solved and I will accept the answer.